# mod_rewrite and HTTP Basic auth

Tags: apache, wordpress, mod-rewrite, basic-authentication

I've got WordPress installed in the root directory of my web server, and it puts the following rewrite rules into the root .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

In the subdirectory `forum` is another PHP application that needs to be protected by HTTP Basic auth. As you would expect there is a `.htaccess` file in the `forum` directory which looks like this:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName MembersArea
AuthUserFile /home/user/public_html/needsecure/.cnk-htpasswd_db/.1_htpasswd
require valid-user
```

Now the `RewriteCond` statements in the root `.htaccess` file should, as far as I can tell, ensure that if a user visits a subdirectory directly then no rewriting should occur. Same for a physical file, and for files named `index.php`. Yet when visiting `/forum`, `/forum/` or even `/forum/index.php` the WordPress 404 page shows.

I tried excluding the `forum` directory from the rewrite rules altogether with

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^forum/
```

before the final rewrite rule, which didn't work. I also tried

```
    RewriteRule ^forum(.*)$ - [L]
```

above all the other rules, and that too didn't work. I even tried `RewriteEngine Off` in `forum/.htaccess` and that didn't work.

If I remove the WordPress rewrite rules it fixes the problem, and if I remove the basic auth rules it fixes the problem. It's only when both are present that it goes wrong: It's as if the basic auth completely breaks the rewrite conditions. Is this a known thing?

Any suggestions? This is getting on my nerves now, I've been messing with it all night.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To exclude the forum directory from the wordpress Rule add the condition as below

```
#if its not the forum directory
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /forum/  [NC]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks. I omitted the final / as I want `example.com/forum` to also work, and I can live with the implications of the missing slash.

Comment: One question though ... why doesn't this work REQUEST_URI? Does basic auth interfere with it?

Comment: @MattLowe It would work with URI too, but you missed the leading slash i.e should have been `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/forum/`

Comment: Nope, I tried both with and without the leading slash. I tried omitting the leading slash as I was under the impression it's not supposed to be there when applying the rule in a .htaccess file ...?